# Turn a Sed function a JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, bash, sed

I have this text normalization function in `bash`

```
normalize_text() {
  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e 's/^/__label__/g' | \
    sed -e "s/'/ ' /g" -e 's/"//g' -e 's/\./ \. /g' -e 's/<br \/>/ /g' \
        -e 's/,/ , /g' -e 's/(/ ( /g' -e 's/)/ ) /g' -e 's/\!/ \! /g' \
        -e 's/\?/ \? /g' -e 's/\;/ /g' -e 's/\:/ /g' | tr -s " "
}
```

I have to transform it into a JavaScript `RegExp`.

This is my partial implementation

```
        text=text.toLowerCase();
        text=text.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, " ");
        text=text.replace(/'/g, " ' ");
        text=text.replace(/"/g, '');
        text=text.replace(/\./g, ' \. ');
        text=text.replace(/,/g, ' \, ');
        text=text.replace(/\(/g, ' ( ');
        text=text.replace(/\)/g, ' ) ');
        text=text.replace(/!/g, ' ! ');
        text=text.replace(/\?/g, ' ! ');
        text=text.replace(/;/g, ' ');
        text=text.replace(/:/g, ' ');
        text=text.replace(/\t+/g,'\t').replace(/\t\s/g,' ').replace(/\t/g,' ');
```

Despite of this implementation, when I'm using the JavaScript version to generate the file (using [FastCSV](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) node library) it will create a bad CSV, resulting in a parsing error when reading like

```
Error: Parse Error: expected: '"' got: 'i'. at 'i met her
```

While when normalizing the file with `sed` and then reading with `FastCSV` it will work properly.

Comment: Could you point out the parts of the sed function that are missing from your JavaScript implementation?

Comment: @vesse good point. It actually should have almost of them, problem is that does not work in the same way, so when parsing the output resulting file, I get an error from the csv library, while using `sed` it will not. Adding more info, thank you.

Comment: The replacements look pretty different… `s/'/ ' /g` appears to have been translated to `.replace(/'/g, " ")`, for example. Try looking at the output one pipe at a time and comparing it to the JavaScript one replacement at a time instead of trying to get the whole thing right at once. Be aware that `'\.' === '.'` in JavaScript, too – you’ll want test cases for each pattern.

Comment: Thanks to point out that different, starting fixing it right now: `text=text.replace(/'/g, " ' ");`. Good suggestion, very difficult to check due to the large file being parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the following code. Demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k8asewqb/).

```
text = text.replace(/^/gm, '__label__');
text = text.replace(/"/g, '');
text = text.replace(/<br \/>/g, ' ');
text = text.replace(/([()!?.',])/g, ' $1 ');
text = text.replace(/[;:]/g, ' ');
text = text.replace(/ +/g, ' ');
```

Explanation:

- sed-s `'s/^/__label__/'` adds `'__label__'` to the beginning of each line. In js you need the multiline modifier, `/m` for that.
- eliminating the quotes is easy to translate from sed to js: `-e 's/"//g'` becomes `text = text.replace(/"/g, '');`
- Replacing line-breaks to space is basically the same: `-e 's/<br \/>/ /g'` becomes `text = text.replace(/<br \/>/g, ' ');`.
- You add spaces around several characters. I lumped them into a single replace: `text = text.replace(/([()!?.',])/g, ' $1 ');`.

  - You can specify multiple characters in a character class: `[...]`. It will match 1 character if it's mentioned within the brackets. There are some tricks though with the `^` and the `-` characters - you can check them [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
  - This character class is within a capturing group: `(...)` so we can refer to it with `$1` within the replacement.
- You want to replace some characters with a space. I lumped them together like this: `text = text.replace(/[;:]/g, ' ');`.
- I'm not familiar with the `tr` command. I believe in this case it replaces multiple spaces with one. You can do it with a regex like this: `text = text.replace(/ +/g, ' ');`.